# Replaying packets with pyusb does not have the expected output

Tags: usb

Working on my Logitech G105 keyboard, to hopefully implement a userspace driver to activate some of its specialized features.

I've captured the usb traffic it outputs when using a windows vm with the official logitech drivers, output of starting the software and setting the m1 led active are in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ntzrmtthihu777/7e23d229056a7e88b878) (usbmon-boot and usbmon-m1 respectively).

Replaying the packets with in python with
`dev.ctrl_transfer(0x21, 0x09, 0x0200, 0x0000, 0x0001)`

and so on results in almost the exact results, however, the data words after = in usbmon are all 00, and the led on the keyboard does not activate.

Comment: No experience with pyusb, but http://sourceforge.net/projects/g15daemon/ might save you some work.

Comment: I've looked into it, it doesn't seem to be very active at the moment and as of right now doesn't support my keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured out my problem. I was doing

`dev.ctrl_transfer(0x21, 0x09, 0x0306, 0x0001, 0x0002)`

in response to

`ffff8800822bbcc0 1231215925 S Co:7:009:0 s 21 09 0306 0001 0002 2 = 0601`

but what I should have done is

`dev.ctrl_transfer(0x21, 0x09, 0x0306, [0x06, 0x01])`

Issue is resolved :D